# Generic Operator in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, operators

Is it possible to define generic operators in Scala?

Scala lets me map arbitrary operators on functions, which is incredibly useful. It seems restrictive however, in a case where I might want the operators to change given the state of the application.

---

To give an example: I have a table with users and a table with their respective relationships. Each relationship has a type, such as: "friends-with", "works-with", etc.
Based on my domain model, I would like the DSL to allow for: `is(john friends-with mary)`. In this case, both `john` and `mary` would be of Object `User`, which would have a generic operator `def <relationship> (a:User): Boolean = {...}`.

---

What I wanted to achieve was exactly what Dynamic would allow me to do (see answer). The description fits perfectly:

> A marker trait that enables dynamic invocations. Instances x of this trait allow calls x.meth(args) for arbitrary method names meth and argument lists args. If a call is not natively supported by x, it is rewritten to x.applyDynamic("meth", args).

More information here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Dynamic.html

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean with <relationship>? The possibility to change the symbol of this method while implementing/overriding it?

Comment: Are you aware of typeclasses? http://marakana.com/s/scala_typeclasses,1117/index.html Googling for 'scala typeclasses' gives you even more dig on. Assuming you want to have `<relationship>` methods for other types, not only User.

Comment: And what do you expect the expression `john friends-with mary` to return?

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize my example was more confusing than helping. What I wanted to do is actually exactly what Dynamic and also sort of typeclasses allow to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at trait Dynamic, which will be available on Scala 2.10 (it's experimental on Scala 2.9).

For example:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class User(name: String) extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(relationship: String)(to: User) =
    Relation(relationship, this, to)
}
case class Relation(kind: String, from: User, to: User)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class User
defined class Relation

scala> User("john") friendsWith User("mary")
res0: Relation = Relation(friendsWith,User(john),User(mary))
```

Comment: Nice code. But I am still not sure what the author of the question means by "generic".

Comment: He doesn't want the type of relationship hard coded in a fixed set of methods but a way using the name of the method called as a parameter to the underlying structure (applyDynamic in this case)